# How do I calculate necessary mosfet turn on/turn off time?

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, speed

I'm trying to measure capacitance of C1 using this design:

[image]
Everything works from 3.3V.

The mosfets is my addition to it - i want to discharge the capacitor after each half-cycle. Everything works OK in low frequencies, but i want to run it on 8Mhz and then it seems, mosfets do not turn on in time. Even more - performance depends on R3 - i had to lower it from 12K to 1K for this to work at 1Mhz.

If i want to discharge C1 in 62.5ns, how do I go about designing this - what mosfet parameters do I look up and what calculations do I make? How gate resistance influences turn on speed?

From what i see 2N7002 has

6ns turn on delay time
4ns rise time
20ns turn off delay time
5ns fall time

if I add it up - it's far less than 62ns.

[Datasheet of 2N7002](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/2N7002.pdf)

**Edit**
Made an inverter as adviced by @rawbrawb

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second mosfet is beng turned on through R3. F3db = 1/(2*pi*30 pf* 1KOhm) = 5.3 MHz
- full settling occurs at 6 time constants => ~ 884 Khz.

gate cap = 30 pF from datasheet

Replace R3 with PMOS transistor to form an inverter.

Comment: do you mean like that? -> see my edit

Comment: Nope - keep the NMOS in there and REPLACE the R3 with a PMOS to make an inverter..  i.e. Gate connected to signal, source(s) of Fet ted together = output, and drain of PMOS on top rail.

Comment: Just noticed you don't have a top rail (power supply)

Comment: Added in the invertor drawing for you.  Sorry above the size.

Comment: oops, i've overriden your edit i guess. is it correct now?

Comment: No worries, you need to have a top rail, you show the PMOS attached to ground which won't work.  Do you have a Vss available?

Comment: my concern is that if Attiny44A has max output current from pin set to 20ma, then by t = Q / I i get t = 0.8nC / 20ma = 40ns, so i guess signal impedance is limiting factor anyway, am i correct?

Comment: i've used circuitlabs ground symbol upside down to designate Vss, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: It occurs to me, that if you have a waveform generator available, then you'll probably have a second output which you can use to drive Q3 directly and get rid of all the other cct's.  (thanks for adding in Q #'s)  Just have it inverted from the input.

Comment: Re: pin output impedance.  It should be OK.  The current limit fixed at 20 mA into a cap gives a straight charge line, not the charge curve like from a RC .  8 MHz = 125 ns so this just eats into that time.

Comment: 8 Mhz is 62.5ns high and 62.5ns low, so ideally i need to turn on, discharge C1 while low and turn off when signal goes high as fast as possible. i guess this is not achievable...